# pi_face_tracker installation problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I followed the instructions to install the uvc_cam and pi_face_tracker but I have a problem installing pi_vision package. What should I do? The problem, I think, is that rosmake doesn't build all the packages required:

```
 tim@ubuntu:~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox$ rosmake pi_vision 
 [ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
 [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['pi_vision']                               
 [ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/tim/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140205-151624
 [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['pi_vision'] to:
 ['ros2opencv', 'pi_face_tracker_gui', 'pi_face_tracker']
 [rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
 [rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs    
 [rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
 [rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs        
 [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                      
 [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild              
 [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
 [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
 [rosmake-2] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                               
 [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib                  
 [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole          
 [rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
 [rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                
 [rosmake-3] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]                                
 [rosmake-2] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters
 [rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
 [rosmake-0] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                     
 [rosmake-3] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps   
 [rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                  
 [rosmake-0] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib             
 [rosmake-3] Starting >>> ogre [ make ]                                          
 [rosmake-3] Finished <<< ogre ROS_NOBUILD in package ogre                       
 [rosmake-3] Starting >>> ogre_tools [ make ]                                    
 [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                       
 [rosmake-3] Finished <<< ogre_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package ogre_tools           
 [rosmake-3] Starting >>> orocos_kdl [ make ]                                    
 [rosmake-3] Finished <<< orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package orocos_kdl           
 [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest                
 [rosmake-0] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]                               
 [rosmake-0] Finished <<< image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package image_transport 
 [rosmake-0] Starting >>> polled_camera [ make ]                                 
 [rosmake-0] Finished <<< polled_camera ROS_NOBUILD in package polled_camera     
 [rosmake-0] Starting >>> camera_calibration_parsers [ make ]                    
 [rosmake-0] Finished <<< camera_calibration_parsers ROS_NOBUILD in package camera_calibration_parsers
 [rosmake-0] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                        
 [rosmake-2] Starting >>> camera_info_manager [ make ]                           
 [rosmake-2] Finished <<< camera_info_manager ROS_NOBUILD in package camera_info_manager
 [rosmake-1] Starting >>> python_orocos_kdl [ make ]                             
 [rosmake-1] Finished <<< python_orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package python_orocos_kdl
 [rosmake-3] Starting >>> kdl [ make ]                                           
 [rosmake-0] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                   
 [rosmake-1] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                        
 [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
 [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                    
 [rosmake-2] Starting >>> mk [ make ]                                            
 [rosmake-1] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                   
 [rosmake-1] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                      
 [rosmake-1] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs              
 [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                    
 [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                        
 [rosmake-3] Finished <<< kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl
  No Makefile in package kdl
 [rosmake-3] Starting >>> diagnostic_msgs [ make ]                               
 [rosmake-3] Finished <<< diagnostic_msgs  No Makefile in package diagnostic_msgs
 [rosmake-3] Starting >>> diagnostic_updater [ make ]                            
 [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosservice  No Makefile in package rosservice          
 [rosmake-2] Finished <<< mk  No Makefile in package mk                          
 [rosmake-2] Starting >>> ros2opencv [ make ]                                    
 [rosmake-1] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                           
 [rosmake-1] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
 [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf                  
 [rosmake-3] Finished <<< diagnostic_updater ROS_NOBUILD in package diagnostic_updater
 [rosmake-3] Starting >>> self_test [ make ]                                     
 [rosmake-3] Finished <<< self_test ROS_NOBUILD in package self_test             
 [rosmake-3] Starting >>> pi_face_tracker [ make ]                               
 [rosmake-0] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                            
 [rosmake-0] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                           
 [rosmake-0] Starting >>> eigen_conversions [ make ]                             
 [rosmake-1] Starting >>> driver_base [ make ]                                   
 [rosmake-0] Finished <<< eigen_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package eigen_conversions
 [rosmake-0] Starting >>> pi_face_tracker_gui [ make ]                           
 [rosmake-1] Finished <<< driver_base ROS_NOBUILD in package driver_base         
 [rosmake-1] Starting >>> uvc_cam [ make ]                                       
 [ rosmake ] All 21 linesos2opencv: 0.7 sec ] [ pi... [ 4 Active 34/39 Complete ]
 {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   mkdir -p bin
   cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
   [rosbuild] Building package ros2opencv
   Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests ros2opencv
   [rospack] Error: package/stack ros2opencv depends on non-existent package opencv2
   
   
   CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
     
   
     Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'ros2opencv'.
     Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
     broken dependency!
   
   Call Stack (most recent call first):
     /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
     CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
   
   
   -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
 [ rosmake ] Output from build of package ros2opencv written to:
 [ rosmake ]    /home/tim/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140205-151624/ros2opencv/build_output.log
 [rosmake-2] Finished <<< ros2opencv [FAIL] [ 0.83 seconds ]                     
 [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package ros2opencv. 
 [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
 [ rosmake ] All 21 linesi_face_tracker: 0.8 sec ]... [ 3 Active 34/39 Complete ]
 {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   mkdir -p bin
   cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
   [rosbuild] Building package pi_face_tracker
   Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests pi_face_tracker
   [rospack] Error: package/stack ros2opencv depends on non-existent package opencv2
   
   
   CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
     
   
     Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
     'pi_face_tracker'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.
     Please fix the broken dependency!
   
   Call Stack (most recent call first):
     /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
     CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
   
   
   -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
 [ rosmake ] Output from build of package pi_face_tracker written to:
 [ rosmake ]    /home/tim/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140205-151624/pi_face_tracker/build_output.log
 [rosmake-3] Finished <<< pi_face_tracker [FAIL] [ 0.83 seconds ]                
 [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package pi_face_tracker. 
 [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
 [ rosmake ] All 21 lines
 {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   mkdir -p bin
   cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
   [rosbuild] Building package pi_face_tracker_gui
   Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests pi_face_tracker_gui
   [rospack] Error: package/stack pi_face_tracker_gui depends on non-existent package rosbridge
   
   
   CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
     
   
     Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
     'pi_face_tracker_gui'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.
     Aborting.  Please fix the broken dependency!
   
   Call Stack (most recent call first):
     /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
     CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
   
   
   -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
 [ rosmake ] Output from build of package pi_face_tracker_gui written to:
 [ rosmake ]    /home/tim/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140205-151624/pi_face_tracker_gui/build_output.log
 [rosmake-0] Finished <<< pi_face_tracker_gui [FAIL] [ 0.83 seconds ]            
 [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package pi_face_tracker_gui. 
 [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
 [rosmake-1] Finished <<< uvc_cam [PASS] [ 3.04 seconds ]                        
 [ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
 [ rosmake ] Built 38 packages with 3 failures.                                  
 [ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
 [ rosmake ] /home/tim/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140205-151624
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126581/pi_face_tracker-installation-problem/) by [timgivois](https://answers.ros.org/users/11671/timgivois/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you're missing the opencv package. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-opencv
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0